# Rails console update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-console

Hello I was trying the update the data in the table using the rails console.

```
Box.where("code = 'learning'").update(duration: 10)
```

I ran this command.

The data is temporarily changing.

```
Box.where("code = 'learning'")
```

When I run this the precious data is being displayed.

Could anyone let me the issue.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please don't use multiple rails versions tags. They are meant to provide context about which version of Rails the question is about. They will not attract any additional attention as they have very few followers unlike the ruby or ruby-on-rails tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`#update`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.3/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update) updates a single record.

```
user = User.find_by(name: 'David')
user.update(name: 'Dave')
```

It will return true/false depending on if the record was actually updated. You can see the validation errors by inspecting the errors object:

```
user.errors.full_messages
```

In non user-interactions situations like seed files and the console it can be helpful to use the bang methods such as `#update!`, `#save!` and `#create!` which will raise an exception if the record is invalid.

If you want to update multiple records at once you need to use [`#update_all`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.3/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update_all):

```
Box.where("code = 'learning'")
   .update_all(duration: 10)
```

This creates a single SQL update statement and is by far the most performant option.

You can also iterate through the records:

```
Box.where("code = 'learning'").find_each do |box|
  box.update(duration: 10)
end
```

This is sometimes necissary if the value you are updating must be calculated in the application. But it is much slower as it creates N+1 database queries.